# How to select more results that match a column that other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering is it possible to select more results from a column that other columns:

```
  public function SameCars() {
    $q = "select * from carads where STATUS='1' and DEL='0' and ADID=".$_REQUEST['carID'];
    $result = $this->QueryResult($q);
    $myprice = intval($result[0]->PRICE);
    $body = $result[0]->BODY;
    $pricelow = $myprice - (30/100 * $myprice);
    $pricehigh = $myprice + (30/100 * $myprice);
    $myyear= $result[0]->YEAR;
    $currentyear = date('Y');
    $yearlow = $myyear - 5;
    if ($yearhigh <= $currentyear-3) {
    $yearhigh = $myyear + 5;
    } else { $yearhigh = $myyear; }
    $samecars = $this->QueryResult("SELECT * FROM carads where BODY LIKE '$body' AND STATUS='1' AND YEAR BETWEEN $yearlow and $yearhigh and DEL='0' and TITLE !='' and TITLE !='-1' and IMAGE1 != '' and IMAGE1 != '-1' and PRICE BETWEEN $pricelow and $pricehigh LIMIT 0,3");
    $i=0;
    if (count($samecars)) {
        foreach ($samecars as $samecar) {$i++;
        if($i==3) $cls="news-row last"; else $cls="news-row";
        echo '<div class="'.$cls.'">
                    <div class="img"><a href="'.$base_path.'detail-page_'.$samecar->ADID.'.html">';

                    if($samecar->IMAGE1!='' && !empty($samecar))
                    echo '<img src="'.$samecar->IMAGE1.'" alt="" height="79" width="89" />';
                    else echo '<img src="'.$base_path.'uploads/no-img.jpg" height="79" width="89"/>';
                    echo '</a></div>
                    <div class="details">
                    <h5><a href="'.$base_path.'detail-page_'.$samecar->ADID.'.html">'.$samecar->TITLE.'</a></h5>
                    <div class="descn">"'.$this->FckContentView($this->closetags(substr($samecar->DESCRIPT, 0,50))).'</div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
        }
    }
}
```

I want `$make` to have 60% importance than other criteria.

Like for example in this query it will echo a list of 3 thumbs with first 3 cars from the `MAKE` "BMW" from the database that matches those criteria. And I would like to output 3 thumbs;  2 thumbs from BMW and 1 from another car that is close within the criteria but different `MAKE`.

Comment: Always style (indent) your code before putting it here...

Comment: Do you mean you want your `WHERE` clause to be `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: I tried fitting it. Indent like in php?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired results.

Comment: @RedFilter Somehow, I need a criteria to be `more visible` than the other. Will edit and add the entire code

Comment: What @GordonLinoff said.

Comment: Is this a PHP question or a SQL question? Please restrict it to one domain only.

Comment: I would get rid of your edit @user3140607 and just include the SQL - as that's what you're interesting in, *right*?

Comment: @HarryDenley Only if it's possible via sql, if not please let it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM carads 
WHERE BODY LIKE '$body' 
AND MAKE = '$make'
AND STATUS='1' 
AND YEAR BETWEEN $yearlow and $yearhigh 
AND DEL='0' 
AND TITLE !='' 
AND TITLE !='-1' 
AND IMAGE1 != '' 
AND IMAGE1 != '-1' 
AND PRICE BETWEEN $pricelow and $pricehigh LIMIT 0,2
```

Then run a second query with

```
SELECT * FROM carads 
WHERE BODY LIKE '$body'
AND MAKE <> '$make' 
AND STATUS='1' 
AND YEAR BETWEEN $yearlow and $yearhigh 
AND DEL='0' 
AND TITLE !='' 
AND TITLE !='-1' 
AND IMAGE1 != '' 
AND IMAGE1 != '-1' 
AND PRICE BETWEEN $pricelow and $pricehigh LIMIT 0,1
```

To try and do this with a single query is POSSIBLE but so messy that I would recommend 2 queries - the LIMITs will make sure you do not put excessive load on your Database

Comment: Yes, something like this. But do i need to change my php code Like adding a new variable?

Comment: 2 separate database calls as opposed to returning one result set using a union? Those two `and` conditions on the same field should be converted to a `not in()`.

Comment: Yes but you have the problem of the 60:40 split then - if you can write a valid mysql query that works do it as I would love to see it but when I was fiddling the 60:40 split on results meant my query was that long and unmanageable that 2 calls seemed better.